# Превратить grob объект или ggplot в растровый массив

Tags: r, ggplot2

Допустим есть графический объект, например график gpplot или сформированный объект grob. Как превратить его в растровый массив? То есть "добраться" до самих пикселей.

Это могла бы быть матрица, где каждый элемент это код цвета, или вообще массив(вектор) где на каждый пиксель приходится 4 числа (RGB и альфаканал) Последний вариант предпочтительней.

Что-то гугл не помогает найти ничего подобного. Как превратить png объект после readPNG() тоже не нашел. Хотя хотелось бы обойтись без промежуточного сохранения файла.

Answer (score 1):

Без сохранения в файл скорее всего не обойтись: объект ggplot2 внутри себя никаких пикселей не содержит. Но с сохраненной картинкой все просто:

```
library(magick)
frink <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")
as.numeric(frink[[1]]) # массив значений пикселей (RGB + альфа-канал)
str(as.numeric(frink[[1]]))
```

> ```
> num [1:445, 1:220, 1:4] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> ```

Comment: Спасибо, а это чем-то отличается от `img <-readPNG('sample.png');
imgBuffer <- as.numeric(img);` ? Кажется вывод одинаковый.

Comment: Используемой библиотекой отличается - библиотека magick очень мощная, там много всего.

Comment: Все-таки это все не то. Но понимаю, что подошёл не с той стороны и неправильно задаю вопрос. Если возможность в R прочитать файл как бинарный? То есть получить вектор, где каждый элемент - байт файла?

Comment: `readBin` попробуйте.